# Is this enough to derive the Klein Gordon equation?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, klein-gordon-equation

I'm sorry if this is trivial but I'm quite lost.

The Klein Gordon field operator $\phi(x)$ in QFT transforms under translations as

$$ U(1,a) \phi(x) U^{-1}(1,a) = \phi(x + a)\,,$$

where

$$U(1,a) = exp(-iP^{\mu}a_{\mu})\,.$$

Is this enough to derive the usual equation of motion

$$(\Box + m^{2})\phi(x) = 0\,?$$

The reason I ask is because in Weinberg's QFT Vol. 1 page 200 the same equation follows from a similar hypothesis. The *one thing* extra that is used in the text for the derivation is the expansion

$$\phi(x) = \int \frac{d^{3}p}{(2\pi)^{3/2}} [u(x,\textbf{p})a (\textbf{p}) + v(x,\textbf{p})a^{\dagger}(\textbf{p})] $$

together with the transformation properties for the creation and annihilation operators

$$ U(1,a) a(\textbf{p}) U^{-1}(1,a) = e^{ipx}a(\textbf{p})\,,$$

which then makes it an easy conclusion to draw. I guess I don't understand what sort of extra information this expansion brings into the theory that allows this.

Just for completeness, my attempts at this led me to
$$i[\phi(x),P_\mu] = \partial_\mu \phi(x)$$
which upon differentiation gives me
$$ \partial^{\mu}\partial_{\mu}\phi(x) = 2P_{\mu}\phi(x)P^{\mu} - 2M^{2}\phi(x)$$

where $M^{2} = P_{\mu}P^{\mu}$ and I assume it commutes with the field (don't know if this is correct), but you see where I was trying to go with this. Thanks.

Comment: The extra assumption encoded in that expansion is that the field is *linear* in creation and annihilation operators. This is only true for free fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The Klein Gordon field operator $\phi(x)$ in QFT transforms under translations as
> $$ U(1,a) \phi(x) U^{-1}(1,a) = \phi(x + a)\,,$$
>
> where
>
> $$U(1,a) = exp(-iP^{\mu}a_{\mu})\,.$$

OK.

> Is this enough to derive the usual equation of motion
>
> $$(\Box + m^{2})\phi(x) = 0\,?$$

No, it is not enough. For example, the $\phi$ operator in a non-free theory (e.g., $\phi^4$ theory) also obeys the same transformation rule, but not the same equation of motion.